# MacbookPro5,3 (mid-2009) won't boot elementary OS

Tags: system-installation, macintosh

I have a MacbookPro5,3 (C2D 2.66, 64 bits EFI, 8GB RAM, nVidia 9400m & 9600m GT) and I am unable to boot into elementary OS.

I have tried both with Apple's boot manager and rEFInd to no avail. I am able to select the USB drive where my Freya image is and then select either Try elementary OS or Install elementary OS.

In all cases, the blinking "e" logo shows, blinks 3-4 times, then the LCD's brightness turns to the maximum and everything hangs. I waited and waited, nothing happens, I have to reset the laptop.

What am I missing? Why can't I boot elementary?

Comment: Are there any boot messages if you click Esc key while booting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exactly the same laptop and I had the same problem.
Press <kbd>e</kbd> on the selected option, after `quiet` add `nomodeset` and press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save changes and boot.
Keep in mind that after installing Freya, the first time you boot, you 'll have the same problem. You need to install nvidia drivers (`Applications > Additional Drivers`) and everything will work fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. My guess is there's something wrong with your iso and/or something wrong with the bootloader on the bootable usb (no kidding, right?) Try using a different program to create your bootable usb. I had to do this too.

Comment: I used two methods: unetbootin and the convert iso to dmg and then `dd` the resulting image. Same result every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  Create elementary OS installer.app to create your bootable USB drive in OSX, it's available here:  https://github.com/linusbobcat/create-elementary-os-installer